# How to use dll created using C# in Visual C++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, c++-cli

Here are the steps what I have done.

1. I have created a .dll file using C# with the content as

   ```
   public static int MyFunction(int dummy)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("I am in dll");
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. I have also created an MFC application (exe) with content as

   ```
   int main()
   {
      int a = MyFunction(0);
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Is this right way to do the call ?

**Note:**

i. I have changed my MFC application to /cl (common language run time support)
ii. I have also added C# file in the MFC's Reference.

**Problems I faced:**

```
     Error  1   error C3861: 'MyFunction': identifier not found 
     Warning    2   warning C4793: 'MyDialog::`vcall'{132}'' : function compiled as native :
```

I have used the following command in the MyDialog.cpp file as a last line, the warning is solved.

`#pragma unmanaged`

Now how to solve the Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# code is placed inside a class, say `MyClass`. If you want to call a static member of this class in C++/CLI, you need to use `MyClass::MyFunction(0)`.
Finally, you would need to add the namespace: `MyNamespace::MyClass::MyFunction(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your C++ program with the /clr flag and use C++/CLI to simply call any .NET code (as long as you include a reference to it).

You could also use a COM callable wrapper for your C# code (compiled in a DLL) -> [check this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)